# Formatting M/D/YY dates in R

Tags: r

I have a column in R that was exported from Excel and it's a datetime of the format "4/3/16" (ie, M/D/YY).  There are no leading zeros in the day or month fields and I'm not sure how to convert this type of value to a date field in R.

I'm new to R so this might be a something obvious that I don't know. Is R the wrong tool to use for data analysis involving dates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Format strings cope fine with that, and base R is all you need:

```
R> d <- as.Date("4/3/16", "%m/%d/%y")
R> d
[1] "2016-04-03"
R>
```

The only thing to remember, really, is that `%y` is for two-digit years whereas `%Y` is for four-digit years.  All the gory details are in the corresponding help pages for `as.Date()`, `strptime()` and friends.

And repeat after me: *Friends never let friends parse dates with string functions*.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mdy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy("4/3/16" )
#[1] "2016-04-03"
```